# [Update]:Save settings of Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio IDE i want to share my project in SVN.Everything was fine i ignored files and then committed by project.Then i try to check out the project and open in Android Studio IDE but the problem i lost the settings in android studio i knew i ignore some files that contains this settings.Can anyone help me on the file that need to commit so that i can restore the settings.The following settings are missing.[image]

[image: Ignore File List]

Answer (score 2):

dont ignore `.gradle`!

project settings usually reside in `.iml` (IDEA markup language I believe), those are settings for the IDE.
More broad and user based settings live und `.idea/`, usually you dont want have them in your source repository.

Comment: I agree. allow gradle or perish! welcome to android studio.

Comment: I allowed .gradle file but still the settings are missing can you please provide me the correct ignore file list to retain my settings.